# Problem with Boto3 SNS SMS publish with OriginationNumber

Tags: boto3, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

We have a very simple use case where are python app sends SMS texts to on-call users when system alerts happen.  I have created in AWS API acccess id/keys, and a toll-free number through Pinpoint.

My publish function looks like this:

```
        try:
            sns = boto3.client('sns',
                               aws_access_key_id='<our api id>',
                               aws_secret_access_key='<our api key>',
                               endpoint_url='https://sns-fips.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
                               config=Config(region_name='us-east-2',
                                             proxies={'https': '<our proxy>'}))
            for o in users:
                number = getattr(o,'number') if getattr(o,'number').startswith('+') else '+1' + getattr(o,'number').replace("-","").replace("(","").replace(")","")
                print('Sending message ' + msg + ' to contact ' + getattr(o,'name') + ' at number ' + number)
                result = sns.publish(PhoneNumber=number, Message=msg, MessageAttributes={'AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber': {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': '+1<our tollfree>'}})
                print(result)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("SMS API EXCEPTION: {0}".format(ex), flush=True)
```

If I don't include the MessageAttributes, the message sends just fine but gets the AWS assigned long number (which is going away soon).  If I go into my SNS dashboard and manually send a message using our tollfree, it goes through.  If change the toll free to something else, it doesn't go through.  So I know the association is there.

I also tried changing the code to use the Boto pinpoint client and get the same behavior, no messaging occurs, no errors.

Using the sns publish, my results come back with a status code of 200, a request id, 0 retry attempts, etc.  So it seems like the messages are being sent.  And I see nothing in the SMS delivery logs.

Am I missing something here?  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, simple solution.  Pinpoint isn't available in east-2, just east-1.  Switched regions and it worked.